# Split "dict" definition up between files

Tags: python, setup-project

I'd like to define the contents of a large dictionary object up between files.  I'm wondering if this is possible in python.

Ideally, this is what I'd like to do:

**Main File:** (dict_object_main.py)

```
# File name: dict_object_main.py

import dict_object_sub1
import dict_object_sub2

dict_object = {}

def doSomeStuffWithTheDictObject:
    ...
    return
```

**1st File that adds a lot of stuff to "dict_object":** (dict_object_sub1.py)

```
# File name: dict_object_sub1.py
from dict_object_main import dict_object

dict_object['sub1'] ={
     'property1':'value1'
    ...
    ,'property9999':'value9999'
}
```

**2nd File that adds a lot of stuff to "dict_object":** (dict_object_sub2.py)

```
# File name: dict_object_sub2.py

from dict_object_main import dict_object

dict_object['sub2'] ={
     'property1':'value1'
    ...
    ,'property9999':'value9999'
}
```

I have something similar set up in javascript.  Is it ok to do it this way in Python or should I be doing it differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `update` method instead.

```
# Same for dict_object_sub1.py or dict_object_sub2.py

from dict_object_main import dict_object
dict_object.update({
    'prop1': 'val1',
    # ...
})
```

**Note:**
I don't think it makes much sense to split the declaration out on two different files. The final memory occupied by the dictionary will be exactly the same in both cases.

**Edit:**
As daveydave400 pointed out in his answer, the importing order is wrong too.

You need at least 3 distinct files (or doing the updates in the importing module):

- A dict_declare.py file, where you declare your dictionary:

  ```
  dict_object = {}
  ```
- A file for each partial dictionary declaration:

  ```
  from dict_object import dict_object

  dict_object.update({
      'prop1': 'val1',
      # ...
  })
  ```
- Your main file:

  ```
  from dict_declare import dict_object
  import dict_object_sub<n>
  # ... repeat

  def doSomeStuffWithTheDictObject:
      ...
      return
  ```

Comment: Cool, would that automatically be initialized when the application was loaded?

Comment: If you import each file manually, yes. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: Why doesn't flipping the order work, it worked for me?  Check out my updated answer, it doesn't have any circular dependence and looks closer to what you originally had.

Comment: @daveydave400: Your updated answer is correct; the first iteration wasn't. If you import the files, even after defining the dictionary, the dictionary itself will not be available in the imported modules and trying to import it from the main file will cause a circular import error.

Comment: Of course, you are totally correct.  When I was testing his stuff I must have typed something wrong because it works correctly...weird.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The first part to my previous answer was wrong.  The lesson I learned is don't have circular dependencies. The following is correct:

Another option is to try this in the main file:

```
from dict_object_sub1 import dict_object_sub1
from dict_object_sub2 import dict_object_sub2
dict_object = {}
dict_object.update(dict_object_sub1)
dict_object.update(dict_object_sub2)
```

Then in both of the sub files do something like this:

```
# dict_object_sub1.py
dict_object_sub1 = {...}
```

Comment: My updated answer gives another option to accomplish the same thing with out a circular dependence.